# Reactive variable has value of undefined when injected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 with options API.

As shown in the code below, in the provider component I provide a reactive version of the object `isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon`. Initially, the value of `isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon` is `ref(true)`, and it gets changed in `onDigitizePolygon`.
in the injector component, in `mounted()` life-cycle callback, I print the values of `inject('isToggled')`, but it is always `undefined`

Why is `inject('isToggled')` `undefined, and how to solve it?

Provider component:

```
<template>
    <button id="idBtnDigitizePolygon" class="clsBtnDigitizePolygon" @click="onDigitizePolygon()" :disabled="isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled">
        test
    </button>
</template>

<script>
import { provide, ref } from 'vue';

let isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon = ref(true);

export default {
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    props: {
        isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onDigitizePolygon() {
            isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.value = !isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.value;
            provide('isToggled', isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon)
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Injector component:

```
<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log('injected', inject('isToggled'))
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Output of log message in created lifecycle callback in injector component:

```
ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue:: inject(InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description);: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

In option API you can use provide inject hooks. (If you want reactive data in the injector, you have to use object in data(not primitive types).)

The working example:

Provider component:

```
<template>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 20px; align-items: flex-start;">
    <AllView />
    <button @click="renderMap('updatedValue')">Set Value</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import AllView from '@/views/AllView.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    AllView,
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      provideMap: this.map,
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      map: {
        data: undefined,
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderMap();
  },
  methods: {
    renderMap(key) {
      this.map.data = key || 'injectedValue';
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Injector component:

```
<template>
  {{ map?.data }}
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  inject: {
    map: {
      from: 'provideMap',
    },
  },
};

</script>
```